# Is arithmetic on the naturals $\omega$-consistent?

Tags: logic, incompleteness, peano-axioms

Is there any first order theory of arithmetic of the natural numbers that is known to be $\omega$-consistent if it is consistent?

If yes, then how?

Comment: $\omega$-consistency implies consistency. PA is $\omega$-consistent as is any theory that has the standard model $\Bbb{N}$ as a model.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking if we can show that there exists a theory of arithmetic on $\mathbb{N}$ such that its consistency implies its $\omega$-consistency. Are you asserting that $\mathbb{N}$ exists and is consistent by fiat? If so, I'm asking basically is there any reason to believe arithmetic on $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed $\omega$-consistent.

Comment: The definition of $\omega$-consistency is contingent on the existence of $\Bbb{N}$. If you are trying to make some more subtle point in your question, please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Ok, that answers my question. I was just wondering if there was any reason to believe any infinite theory is $\omega$-consistent, if one is not convinced of the existence of some true (intuitively $\omega$-consistent) arithmetic on $\mathbb{N}$. It appears then that the answer is no. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So basically one way the world could be is that all infinite theories are $\omega$-inconsistent, even if not all are inconsistent. That's what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

The *empty theory* over the language of arithmetic is certainly $\omega$-consistent.

This theory has the property that whenever it proves some formula $\phi$, you can replace every atomic formula $t_1=t_2$ by "true" and ignore all of the quantifiers, and the resulting Boolean expression will then evaluate to true. (Intuitively this is because the one-element universe is a model, but you can verify it purely syntactically one inference rule at a time).

Therefore it is impossible for the theory to prove both $\neg\phi(0)$ and $(\exists x)\,\phi(x)$, since the two Boolean expressions they translate to are each other's negations.

---

(This same argument also works for full Peano Arithmetic *minus* the axiom stating that $0$ is not a successor).

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a fact that doesn't answer your question literally as stated, but may be interesting to you and other readers of this question: **if you accept the axioms of ZFC, then pretty much any theory of arithmetic is $\omega$-consistent.** Namely,

> **Theorem (ZFC).**  For any theory of arithmetic $\mathcal{T}$ such that $\mathbb{N} \vDash \mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}$ is $\omega$-consistent.$^1$

Here "theory" means "set of axioms", and $\vDash$ is the satisfaction relation from model theory: $\mathcal{M} \vDash \mathcal{T}$ means that the structure $\mathcal{M}$ (in this case, natural numbers with addition, multiplication, etc.) satisfies all of the axioms $\mathcal{T}$.

Since pretty much any theory of $\mathbb{N}$ is supposed to start from *true* axioms, that is axioms we believe are actually true about $\mathbb{N}$, most such theories will be $\omega$-consistent. In particular:

> **Corollary (ZFC).** Peano Arithmetic (PA) and Robinson Arithmetic (RA) are $\omega$-consistent.

This may be a bit surprising! So what is the basis for these results? The theorem requires a *strong meta-theory,* in this case ZFC, in which we can develop all of model theory (in particular, in which we can define what a formula is, what a theory is, and what satisfaction $\vDash$ means). In such a meta-theory, there is also an object called $\mathbb{N}$, the natural numbers (in ZFC the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ is given as an axiom). Because such an object exists, we can then show that *any correct theory* (one that consists of axioms which are true about $\mathbb{N}$) is $\omega$-consistent.

If we do not get to assume strong meta-theory axioms like ZFC, but instead are wondering about the $\omega$-consistency of a theory like PA in a much weaker theory, then we may no longer be able to show that PA is $\omega$-consistent.

---

$^1$ *Proof of the theorem:* We proceed by contradiction: let $P(x)$ be a formula with one free variable, such that $\mathcal{T}$ proves (implies) $P(0)$, $P(1)$, and so on, but $\mathcal{T}$ also proves (implies) $\exists x. \lnot P(x)$.

Now since $\mathbb{N} \vDash \mathcal{T}$, $\mathbb{N} \vDash \varphi$ for any logical consequence (implication) $\varphi$ of the axioms $\mathcal{T}$. Therefore,
$\mathbb{N} \vDash P(i)$ for all natural numbers $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and moreover, $\mathbb{N} \vDash \exists x. \lnot P(x)$. But these statements are in direct contradiction: by definition, the latter statement means that there exists some natural number $j$ such that $\mathbb{N} \vDash \lnot P(j)$, which is the exact opposite of the former statement. So we are done.